# Decimal in localized nib. How to get it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

In my nib there are 3 fields displaying a decimal number from a string (initWithFormat %f).
When I make my nib local those fields has to display the numbers with a decimal comma instaed of a decimal point. Localizition works well for the labels etc. due to a localalized (dutch) nib. The decimal separator is still a point.

What am I overlooking?

EDIT:
I have tried the options mentioned in the answers but I'm not able to get it to work. In my dutch localization the values still are displayd wit a decimal dot instaed of a comma.
Can you help met with for example this bit of code?

```
//display accuracy
NSString *acc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
accuracy.text=acc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `initWithFormat:` use, for example, [localizedStringWithFormat:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) from the NSString class.

Comment: @ Daniel Thamk you for your reply. As far as I knows does localizedStringWithFormat need a .strings file. I don't see how I get de decimal (and thousands) separater to work properly using this technique.

Comment: As always, short after asking for more help I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `NSNumberFormatter` instead of string formats. `NSNumberFormatter` allows you to format numbers that display properly based on the user's locale. You can setup the formatter for showing numbers as decimals, percents, currency, or scientific notation. There are many options for specifying the number of decimal places, rounding, and many other aspects of how the number should be formatted.

Comment: @ maddy Thank you for your reply. I think I don't understand it properly so I've added some code to my question. How do I get that code to work properly. Please advice.

Comment: As always, after I asked form more help, I found it. Thank you